# Adding user defined types in SOLR schema

Tags: solr, solrnet

Iam using SOLR as my search query database.
My current requirement is to post this Document on SOLR database.

```
namespace SOLRApp
{
    public class Table1Document
    {
        public Table1Document()
        {
            MobileNos = new List<int>();
            EducationalDetails = new List<EducationalDetails>();
        }

        [SolrUniqueKey("ID")]
        public string ID { get; set; }

        [SolrField("FirstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [SolrField("LastName")]
        public string LastName{ get; set; }

        [SolrField("MobileNos")]
        public List<int> MobileNos { get; set; }

        [SolrField("EducationalDetails")]
        public List<EducationalDetails> EducationalDetails { get; set; }

    }

    public class EducationalDetails
    {
        public EducationalDetails()
        {
            Details = new List<Details>();
        }

        public List<Details> Details { get; set; }
    }

    public class Details
    {
        [SolrField("IntitutionName")]
        public string IntitutionName { get; set; }

        [SolrField("EnrollDate")]
        public DateTime EnrollDate { get; set; }

        [SolrField("PassoutDate")]
        public DateTime PassoutDate { get; set; }

        [SolrField("InstituteRating")]
        public int InstituteRating { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And for that I have added this schema file with field as follows.

```
        <field name="ID" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="FirstName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="LastName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
        <field name="MobileNos" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
        <field name="EducationalDetails" type="EducationalDetails" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true">
            <field name="Details" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true">
                <field name="IntitutionName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
                <field name="EnrollDate" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
                <field name="PassoutDate" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
                <field name="InstituteRating" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
            </field>
        </field>
```

I would like to know how can we add user defined datatypes in SOLR. Like in my example, 'EducationalDetails' is a user defined datatype (class). Can any one tell me how to add that in SOLR.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: guys please reply.... if you are not understanding my question the let me know..

Comment: see http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaDesign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own types with the `<fieldType />` tag, for example:

```
<fieldType name="cstring" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" updateOffsets="true" />
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="\s+$" replacement="" />
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

However, as you can notice it's nothing like you want. The stuff you want (subfields, ...) is not possible with Solr. Solr is a **document** based store, not an "object" store or how you want to see it.

The best solution I can come up with is to create multiple "types" of documents. You scheme should look like:

```
<field name="ID" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="FirstName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="LastName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="MobileNos" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />

<!-- Education details -->
<field name="IntitutionName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="EnrollDate" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="PassoutDate" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="InstituteRating" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="DocumentID" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="Type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

If you add a Table1Document to Solr, you only provide the ID, FirstName, LastName and MobileNos fields (and additionally you can use the **Type** field and add "Table1Document"

If you add an EducationDetails object, you only provide the InstitutionName, EnrollDate, PassoutDate and InstituteRating field. In the **DocumentID** field you put a reference to the ID of the Table1Document they should belong to. In the **Type** field you can add "EducationDetails".

If you now want to retrieve your Table1Document you use a query like:

```
type:Table1Document AND id:1
```

To get the EducationDetails that belong to it you can use a query like:

```
type:EducationDetails AND DocumentID:1
```

Afterwards you can still construct an object with the structure you like.

Comment: First of all, thank you Dimitri for posting a reply. I understood what you said. But don't u think that this would create multiple records of ID: 1 if there are multiple EducationalDetails mapped against ID:1. If yes, then is this the only SOLR can store data.? Cant solr store multiple nodes within a node. eg: like in my case multiple 'Details' node under one 'EducationalDetail' node.

Comment: You can only store multiple primitive fields within a node as far as I know. There will only be 1 document with ID 1. You will however get multiple documents with DocumentID 1 (all details that belong to the Table1Document with ID 1). You will probably have to introduce another index too (for EducationDetails).