# How to create bind multiple nodes within a single node in SOLR schema file

Tags: solr, solrnet

Iam using SOLR as my search query database.
I am facing difficulty in binding multiple nodes (a collection) within a node in SOLR. Can any body tell me the schema for the same.

My Document is as follows

```
namespace SOLRApp
{
    public class Table1Document
    {
        public Table1Document()
        {
            MobileNos = new List<int>();
            EducationalDetails = new List<EducationalDetails>();
        }

        [SolrField("FirstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [SolrField("MobileNos")]
        public List<int> MobileNos { get; set; }

        [SolrField("EducationalDetails")]
        public List<EducationalDetails> EducationalDetails { get; set; }

    }

    public class EducationalDetails
    {
        public EducationalDetails()
        {
            Details = new List<Details>();
        }

        public List<Details> Details { get; set; }
    }

    public class Details
    {
        [SolrField("IntitutionName")]
        public string IntitutionName { get; set; }

        [SolrField("EnrollDate")]
        public DateTime EnrollDate { get; set; }

        [SolrField("PassoutDate")]
        public DateTime PassoutDate { get; set; }

        [SolrField("InstituteRating")]
        public int InstituteRating { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And my schema file is as shown below.

```
        <field name="FirstName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="MobileNos" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
        <field name="EducationalDetails" type="EducationalDetails" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true">
            <field name="Details" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true">
                <field name="IntitutionName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
                <field name="EnrollDate" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
                <field name="PassoutDate" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
                <field name="InstituteRating" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
            </field>
        </field>
```

My main question is what would be the type of 'EducationalDetails' node. This gives me error of

```
Cannot initialize type 'SOLR.EducationalDetails' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'.
```

I would like to know how can we add user defined datatypes in SOLR. Like in my example, 'EducationalDetails' is a user defined datatype (class). Can any one tell me how to add that in SOLR.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977520/adding-user-defined-types-in-solr-schema

Comment: See also https://code.google.com/p/solrnet/issues/detail?id=49#c6